# Compute the characteristic path length for each of the following graphs: $P_{2k}, P_{2k+1},C_{2k}, C_{2k+1}, K_n, K_{m,n}$.

Tags: graph-theory

Could someone just show me how to do one of these?

Definition of characteristic path length is the average distance between vertices where the average is taken over all pairs of distinct vertices.

Answer (score 1):

I'll show you how to do $K_n$ as that's the easiest. The distance between any two distinct vertices is $1$, and the average of a bunch of $1$s is $1$, so that's the answer. Assuming $n\ge2$, that is; if a graph has only one vertex the average is undefined.

That was too easy, so I'll do $K_{m,n}$ too. Let's assume $m,n\ge1$, so that the graph is nontrivial and connected. There are two cases: the distance between two distinct points is $1$ if they are in different parts of the bipartition, $2$ if they are in the same part. There are $mn$ pairs of the first kind, $\binom m2+\binom n2$ of the second kind, and $mn+\binom m2+\binom n2=\binom{m+n}2$ pairs all told, so the average is
$$\frac{mn\cdot1+\binom m2\cdot2+\binom n2\cdot2}{\binom{m+n}2}=1+\frac{\binom m2+\binom n2}{\binom{m+n}2}$$
or something like that.